# Some fonts are not showing up

Tags: text-object, osx, file-browser

I am trying to use a font called DIN Medium, which is a Postscript font, in Blender.

[image]

However, when I browse, I cannot see the font listed in the folder:

[image]

Are my eyes failing me, or are some font formats not supported in Blender?
I couldn't find any info on this online when I searched.

Comment: I'm not sure Blender supports post script fonts directly

Comment: Thanks! maybe that's worth being converted into an answer if there's an official statement somewhere? Also I didn't find an addon to solve that, quite weird

Comment: I would but I'm not sure if this is really true. Could not find anything online from my superficial research to confirm or refute my theory.

Comment: This was all I could find, but it is far from an official statement https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341336-Load-a-font-into-blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On *nix systems blender uses [freetype](https://www.freetype.org), which supports postscript fonts.

When you choose a font file the [file browser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/file_browser/introduction.html) applies a filter based on the filename extension. The file you show doesn't have an extension so would not be listed as a supported font file.

If the file doesn't have an extension or it is not in the list of known extensions then you can turn off the file filter so that all files are available to be selected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It does make the font appear in the list, but it is listed as a "0kb" file and cannot be used/selected. So if these fonts are supported, how do I use them? http://imgur.com/a/l0esl

Comment: If it isn't recognised as a font file and you can't get the font in other formats then you either need to convert it to truetype or opentype... or find another font that looks the same. You might be able to use the font in inkscape and export as svg to get the text into blender.

Answer (score 11):

The installed fonts which are not shown in C:/windows/fonts are located at

C:/Users/USer Name/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts
You can browse through and select the fonts..
[image]

Comment: I am sorry if this was unclear but the question is for MAC users 

Comment: MicroMachine Sryy haven't noticed that..