# Fonts not showing up

Tags: font

I have several fonts, ttf, that are installed on my computer and show up in everything else. For some reason, Blender doesn't show some of them, I don't know why. Can anyone help / suggest / point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77216/

Comment: Most likely your problem is related to malware_656's answer at quellenform's link. The problem is, that Blender by default opens the folder C:\Windows\Fonts to choose a font from, however not all installed fonts are necessarily located in this folder. Some of them can be found here: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts and they get shown alongside all the other installed fonts.